# Configuring Fail2ban for the r4032login module

Tags: 8, security

Recently, I installed fail2ban on my server to help prevent bots from abusing the site.

I have the r4032login module installed and it is writing to the log, but it is using HTTP status 302 for the redirect to the login page.

I'm wondering what would be the easiest way to have fail2ban work alongside the r4032login.

Here is a sample log entry:

```
ddd.ddd.ddd.ddd - - [12/May/2019:14:46:26 -0400] "GET /node/1/edit HTTP/1.1" 302 4305 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36"
```

https://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

https://www.drupal.org/project/r4032login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Fail2Ban v0.10.2, I edited two files in the `/etc/fail2ban` directory.

I added the following entry to jail.local:

```
[apache-forbidden]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = apache-forbidden
logpath = %(apache_access_log)s
maxretry = 3
findtime = 600
bantime  = 600
```

For `filter.d/apache-forbidden.conf` I have the following:

```
[INCLUDES]

before = common.conf

[Definition]

failregex = <HOST> - - .*HTTP/[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?" 302
```

The 302 at the end is to reflect the redirect code for r4032login module.

**NOTE**: 302 redirects by other modules and Apache might also trigger a ban. Please see the comment below to mitigate this effect.

Comment: I would expect all 302 redirects to trigger a ban with these parameters... surely? The saving grace is that normal users don't typically trigger 302 redirects frequently from the same host (unless that host is a NAT external IP for a company or similar). Consequently, I would suggest making sure that the retry parameter is relatively large and the time is relatively short. Monitor the logs over a long-ish period to make sure.  If you can, change the "custom log" parameter in apache config so the logs show any additional info that can restrict the ban trigger.